# What is the intended flow of Tkinter mainloop? Tkinter is freezing algo's time flow

Tags: python, algorithm, tkinter, structure, python-multithreading

I am new to using tkinter and although I can make things in Python, I am still learning.

For me, Tkinter is just an output window or log window.  The code that I am writing is very calculation-heavy and not really about the interface at all.  I was hoping to just do all of the algo flow in another module and just throw something like drawOutput() at TKinter.  But it seems like the Mainloop () locks the time and flow of the program.

Is it intended that I place my entire algorithm's flow within the loop of TKinter???

Or, could it be multithreaded so Tkinter is stuck perpetually taking draw GUI assignments but not anything to do with my main software?

I really want all of my time to flow in my module and to just toss things over the wall to Tkinter to draw them without stopping or pausing the time flow of my main algo at all.  Is this possible and how?  Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://gordonlesti.com/use-tkinter-without-mainloop/

Comment: As long as entire `tkinter` stays in one thread, its fine to use multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

`mainloop()` does as you say - it stalls the program where it is until the GUI loop exits. What you need to do is have your program logic in a separate thread (possibly an entirely separate class).

```py
import Threading
import tkinter as tk

class worker(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.terminating = False
    # setup important stuff here

  def terminate(self):
    self.terminating = True

  def start(self):
    workerthread = threading.Thread(target=self.do_work, name="myapp-worker")
    workerthread.start()

  def do_work(self, args):
    while not self.terminating:
      # Do stuff that needs to carry on forever until someone presses stop in the GUI

class GUI(object):
  def __init__(self):
    # Instantiate GUI variables here

  def set_worker(self, myworker):
    # Keep a reference to the connected worker object. Avoid doing this both ways or you'll get a circular reference.
    self.worker = myworker

  def setup(self):
    root = tk.Tk()
    self.root = root
    # Set up all your widgets here, but *don't* call mainloop()

  def close(self):
    # Call this from your close button in the GUI
    self.worker.terminate()

  def run(self):
    self.root.mainloop()

def main():
  myworker = worker()
  mygui = GUI()
  mygui.set_worker(myworker)
  mygui.setup()
  myworker.start()
  mygui.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```